# The correct indexation in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

Suppose I have a `Matrix <float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor> A` in `Eigen`. When i write following code:

```
cout << "Number of Columns of A is: "<< A.cols() << endl;
cout << "Number of Rows of A is: "<< A.rows() << endl;
```

I get following result:

```
Number of Columns of A is: 129
Number of Rows of A is: 600
```

According to the above results, i expect when i write following code, i get `Exception Error` but that does not happen and it print a value!!! WHY??!!

```
cout << A(500,140);
```

Comment: It seems to be an Undefined behavior : what happen isn't defined, so your soft can crash, display value, or anything else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in Eigen docs, matrix coefficients can be accessed either via `m(i,j)` or `m.coeff(i,j)`/`m.coeffRef(i,j)` (plus `m[i]` and `m.x(),...` for the special vector case).

Now, the 'm(i,j)' variant *is* range-checked *unless* the `NDEBUG` or `EIGEN_NO_DEBUG` macros are defined. Typically, the former macro is defined for 'release' builds, so no range checks will be performed in that case. The rationale is that Eigen is a performance oriented library, checks have a cost, so it makes sense enabling them for debugging purposes only.

The `m.coeff(i,j)` form is never checked.

When no check is performed, any attempt to invoke a coefficient accessor out of range is a precondition violation, this means the behaviour is undefined.

Generally speaking, you should minimize the use of indexed access in favor of higher level, block/linear algebra operations (Eigen has plenty of them); your code will result more compact, more readable (well, at least, to an algebra-aware reader), more correct (less risk of out of range accesses) and (possibly much) faster.

Comment: Thanx guy. yes you're righ. I'm in `release` mode. so why when i write `cout << A(700,1)` I have `Exception`?! In other word when I get out of row range i have `Exception` but i don't have in col range.

Comment: @Saeid the short answer: undefined behaviour means undefined behaviour; anything can happen, including an exception for whatever reason. If you want to know the *exact* reason why your (illegal) code throws, you'll need to produce a [mcve] and use a debugger to see what's going on ...